# Is the half iterate of $2\sinh(x)$ - expanded from fixed point $0$ - analytic near the real line $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, tetration, complex-dynamics

Is the half iterate of $2\sinh(x)$ - expanded from fixed point $0$ - analytic near the real line $\mathbb{R}$?

I know this function has 2 other fixed points apart from $0$, so I'm not sure.

Also does analytic at some place imply it satisfies its functional equation(being half-iterate of $2\sinh(x)$) at that place ?

Comment: I admit I got this question from http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=781 being a question from tommy1729 @ the tetration forum.

Comment: Yes, it should be analytic at the real axis.  I haven't had time to think about it in much detail.   But in the past, I generated the equations and taylor series for $\text{2sinh}^z$, for iterating 2sinh from its fixed point of zero.  It acts like 2^z near the fixed point.

Comment: That last sentense seems a bit trivial , if a fixpoint of $f$ has derivative $b$ then the behaviour of $f^z$ is always $b^z$. Also it is not so hard to find a taylor series for the half iterate bu that does not prove analytic near the real line , especially when we have other fixpoints.

Comment: Ok, I need to work on this one too. The other fixed points are near +/-1.895i, but the function has two inverses there, so that may not be a singularity.  I think its more likely the nearest singularity, is +/-2i, where the inverse has a derivative of zero. Also, I can now generate the formal half iterate power series.  ?? it should equal the abel/inverse abel function from the schroeder function, since the multiplier=2.

Comment: We know it is infinitely differentiable for real $x>0$, so a " nice " bijection to a fourier series could answer it